# How to call a bat from from a java program

Tags: java, swing, batch-file

I have created a bat file to call a java class. Now I have created a GUI in swing. In that swing I have a button as start and for that I have action Listener in which I created the following code

```
public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
    try 
    {

        File file = new File("F:/myprog/start.bat");

        Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);

    } catch (IOException e)

    {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);

}
```

When I run click the button I get "`Error: Could not find or load main class`"

Batch file :

```
javac *.java
java websphinx.workbench.Workbench
 pause
```

When I click the bat file the application is running. But from Java program when I call this bat file I get the error. What went wrong?

Comment: Can you use: Runtime.getRuntime().exec('Path to bat'); ?

Comment: @Alex 
BAT FILE 


javac *.java
java websphinx.workbench.Workbench
pause

Comment: so you bat file is executing, its the content in in it that is throwing error. The ` websphinx.workbench.Workbench pause` is that a main class?

Comment: Call a bat? Do this: http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m3xdy1jJL31qbu4f8o1_500.gif

Comment: @MukulGoel Workbench is the main class and when I click the bat file the application runs with out any problem.

Comment: @Thomas  not that bat...

Comment: what @fatfredyy has suggested is absolutely correct and appropriate

Comment: @Thomas : if this was anything else people might have discouraged this behavior or even complained , but this is awesome

Comment: Murali : you might want to see my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java one usually runs a command while Runtime.getRuntime().exec, you'll need to pass cmd.exe as the file to run, and then the batch name as a parameter.

```
try {
     Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "F:/myprog/start.bat"});
     InputStream in = p.getInputStream();
     OutputStream out = p.outputStream();
} catch (IOException e){
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A batch file in intself is not an executable and is normaly run within its interpreter, thus you will need to start it with the cmd.exe

Try the following

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "F:\\myprog\\start.bat");
Process p = pb.start();
```

An alternative to this is:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start F:/myprog/start.bat");
```

The Processbuilder is the preferred alternative, though. It gives you much more control over the external process, as you can instruct your program to wait for the batch file to complete its execution or run concurrent to it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start F:/myprog/start.bat");
```

Answer (score 1):

i THINK its not a batch file issue,

looking at `Error: Could not find or load main class`

it looks like a classpath issue

you might need to improve your batch file

```
javac *.java
java -cp yourdrive:\path\to\class websphinx.workbench.Workbench
 pause
```

see the `-cp` variable.

The thing that when you execute batch file as is it runs and when from your program it gives exception , could be because of change of scope. your java class and your batch file may not be at same location to say.

Comment: yes. the java class and batch file are in different folder. But I also checked keeping the bat file in the class file folder and calling from my GUI program But still the error persists.

Comment: @Murali : does any of the other answers help ? changing the way batch is being called?

Comment: @Murali : can you update your question with your project structure? where the calling java is..where the batch is, and where is the Workbench.java?

Comment: **F:\project\data\collect - path of batch file** <br/>


**F:\project\data\collect\websphinx\workbench - path of class file**

Comment: @Murali : there is an edit button to bottom left of your question. edit it and update the post. its not readable here. neither I want to read it here

Comment: I am using my eclipse IDE and I running my GUI program in that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19989/discussion-between-mukul-goel-and-murali)

Answer (score 0):

You use the [`Runtime#exec`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) method for this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", "F:\\myprog\\start.bat" });
```

Note that the program you're really running is `cmd.exe`, with the `/c` switch, followed by the batch filename with the path in Windows format.

Comment: Refer to op comments on the question. this is not the actual problem.

Comment: @MukulGoel: Quite possibly. I've read the question and the comments and now I have no idea what the OP is asking.

Comment: Yea same here. he is not sure what he is asking. what he is doing is, there is a button on whose click he calls a batch which first compiles all the files in current directory then make a call to `pause` class. now this statement is throwing the error : `Error: Could not find or load main class`. i think that is it and that is not a _unable to run batch_ error

Comment: @MukulGoel hey I have an application ok. I used to run the application from cmd. So to avoid I created a batch file to run the application. To give more user GUI I created swing with some buttons in it. When I click one of the button I have to run the batch file which call the application. this is it...